# Using Linear Regression to Analyze Trends

Tags: regression, trend

I've seen posts similar to this, but I've yet to come across a satisfactory answer. Given that...

I've recently begun to study trend analysis, and I came upon a report that stated, "...there was a statistically significant downward trend in cancer mortality from 2000 through 2010." Later in the document, it stated that all trend analyses were conducted using linear regression.

My question is, how would linear regression be used to demonstrate such a finding? It's my understanding that (simple) linear regression is used to model the relation between two continuous variables (i.e., you're computing how much variance exhibited by one variable is accounted for by the presence of another variable). In light of this, how would such a technique be used to demonstrate a significant change in the rate of cancer mortality from one year to the next (or across multiple years)? Thank you.

Comment: If by trend you mean an increase(decrease) in one variable tends to follow an increase (decrease) in the other. then linear regression would make sense.

Comment: The most simple case: fit simple linear regression where mortality is a dependent variable and time is the independent variable, and then check if the coefficient for mortality is statistically significant. Notice however that linear regression is not the best tool for such analysis

Comment: What alternative would be preferred? Some form of non-interrupted time-series analysis?